# Rails 4, Active Record query returns ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I want to retrieve data from my database and show it in a view.

My controller is:

bancas_controller.erb

```
def show
  @user = current_user
  @a=Banca.find_by(user_id: @user.id)
end
```

The view is:

```
banca: <%=@a%>
```

My model has some attributes: `num`, `scadenza` and `user_id`. I don't understand why my view looks like this:

```
banca: #<Banca:0xb715330>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just doing

```
@a=Banca.find_by(user_id: @user.id)
```

This resturns a record with some desired id. To get the desired attribute use

```
@a.attribute_name
@a.name
@a.email
@a.gender
```

In case you want to see all poperties use `@a.inspect`.

Comment: `find` will do that, `find_by` will not.

Answer (score 0):

`<%=@a%>` will run the code in the erb tag, and then call `to_s` on the result.  If you call `to_s` on an ActiveRecord object then you get the result you saw.  You need to decide how you want to display the data associated with the object, in the erb tag.  eg

```
banca: <%= @a.scadenza %>
```

or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

Find by is a dynamic finder, it's like using a where clause, even if there is only one it will return an Active Record relation.  Just pop `.first` on the end to get the first one if that is what you want.

`@a=Banca.find_by(user_id: @user.id).first`

Answer (score 0):

@a is an object . In the view do this @a.inspect to see it's properties. To iterate over it use .each or .map.